# How to test a method inside a static method with Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a class with a factory method like this:

```
import {AggregateRoot} from '@nestjs/cqrs'

class MyClass extends AggregateRoot {
  static create(condition: boolean): MyClass {

    const newMyClass = new MyClass()

    if (condition) {
      newMyClass.apply(new DomainEvent())
    }

    return newMyClass
  }
}
```

I want to test if the method `doSomething()` is called during the creation of the new object.

I don't know how to mock it, because the object will be created using the factory method. The method I want to test is inside the object, so I can't use it before the object is created.

Comment: You don't mock it, it's part of the class you're supposed to be testing. Presumably the real implementation doesn't just log something, so test that the _behaviour_ is correct.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is just the example, not my real code. In my real code, I don't log anything and use the third-party library, so I don't know the real behavior behind that. That's why I want to test the call.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know the behaviour? What are you using the third-party library _for_? Give a [mre].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited my question. I am using NestJS CQRS. In the if block, I want to raise an event.